# Create a mixin for the given code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mixins

I am having the following css code.

```
 box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0px #ccc, 0px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 10px 0 0px    #ccc, 5px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 15px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 15px 0 0px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0px #ccc, 0px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 15px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 15px 0 0px #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0px #ccc, 0px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 15px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 15px 0 0px #ccc;
```

Is it possible to create mixin for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Create mixins via the @mixin rule. The `@mixin` keyword must be followed by the mixin name and a declaration block.

The following lines define a mixin, and give it three property-value pairs:

```
@mixin .shadow{
 box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0px #ccc, 0px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 10px 0 0px    #ccc, 5px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 15px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 15px 0 0px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0px #ccc, 0px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 15px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 15px 0 0px #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0px #ccc, 0px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 5px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 10px 0 0px #ccc, 0px 15px 0 0px #ccc, 5px 15px 0 0px #ccc;
}
```

Comment: how can i call this  mixin inside another class

Comment: you can use the `>` child selector. It means immediate children will get  affected.